# Classification of GPS trajectory

Tags: gps

I need a detailed description of a GPS trajectories. I don't need to know what a GPS trajectory is, I already know it. Exactly I need a paper (better if scientific cut) that talk about different type of trajectories. e.g.: Difference in pedestrian, marine and car  and highlight what difference presents from each other, can anyone help?

Best regards

Comment: Are you looking for an existing "mode detection" algorithm? Or do you want to create one?

Comment: No, I just need to know the features that characterize different types of trajectories. e.g.: Pedestrian path are different from vehicle path because the first show low velocity and frequent change in heading. Marine traffic have no altitude feature. And so on...

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in the [GeoLife](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1367532) stream of reasearch (PDF [here](http://www2008.org/papers/pdf/p247-zhengA.pdf)) in which transportation mode is inferred from raw GPS tracks. Yan et al. also work on [semantic enrichment](http://icdt.tu-dortmund.de/proceedings/edbticdt2011proc/WebProceedings/papers/edbt/a24-yan.pdf) of GPS tracks.

Comment: I already know these papers. Usefull but they are focus on how to do inference on trajectories and understand the type. It seems quite poor about description, and I need a description about it.

Answer (score 0):

Two pointers that might be of some interest:

---

An approach that defines an algorithm to cluster trajectories including information about the direction of movement. There is pseudocode inside the paper demonstrating this approach, however I haven't seen an implementation of that.

> Rocha, J. A. M. R.; Times, V. C.; Oliveira, G.; Alvares, L. O. &
>   Bogorny, V. (2010), [**DB-SMoT**: A direction-based spatio-temporal
>   clustering method](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~vania/artigos/db-smot.pdf)., in 'IEEE Conf. of Intelligent Systems' , IEEE,
>   , pp. 114-119 .

---

[**Weka-STPM**](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~alvares/software.html) - Semantic Trajectory Preprocessing Module ([alternative source](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/~vania/software.html)). A module that extends [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) data mining toolset. It aims at mining trajectories in a higher abstraction level. Papers of interest detailing this solution:

> [Weka-STPM: from trajectory samples to semantic trajectories](http://www.inf.ufrgs.br/~alvares/software/WSL2010.pdf)
>
> [Weka-STPM: a Software Architecture and Prototype for Semantic
>   Trajectory Data Mining and Visualization](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-9671.2011.01246.x/abstract)

---